# css animation scale not working

Tags: css, animation, scale

I'm creating a animation with css keyframes.
I have this:

```
@keyframes experience {
0% {
-webkit-transform: scale(0,0); 
        transform: scale(0,0);
-webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
        transform: translateY(40px);
opacity: 1;
}
60% {
-webkit-transform: scale(1,1); 
        transform: scale(1,1);
-webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
        transform: translateY(40px);
opacity: 1;
}
100% {
-webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
        transform: translateY(0px);
opacity: 1;
}
}
```

Everything works except for the Scale property it scales in one go instead of animate it.
I work with Jquery waypoints plugin and the div has the class

```
.workitem {
    position: relative;
    width: 1000px;
    height: 200px;
    background-color: #333;
    margin: 0 auto; 
    opacity: 0;
    -webkit-transform: scale(0);
        transform: scale(0);
}
```

When the waypoint hits i add the class

```
.experience {
     -webkit-transform: scale(0);
             transform: scale(0);
     -webkit-animation: experience 2s ease-in forwards ;
             animation: experience 2s ease-in forwards ;
}
```

which uses the above animation.

Comment: Can you put this in a jsfiddle for me to help you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you actually are overriding your `scale` transform.. take a look at the following css:

```
    transform: scale(0,0);
    transform: translateY(40px);
```

This would be the same as setting something like this:

```
    color: red;
    color: blue;
```

In this case, you would expect your element's `color` property to be `blue`, as that style rule comes second and overrides the one for `red`.

It's the same with `transform`, even though you are using different types of transformations, they still share the same `transform` property.

You see the abrupt jump because you start with it set to `scale(0,0)`, but as soon as the animation begins, you are now only translating the element, not scaling, so it reverts to normal immediately.

You can get around this by declaring your styles like this, instead:

```
    transform: scale(0,0) translateY(40px);
```

And obviously adding in all your proper vendor prefixing from there!

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
@-webkit-keyframes
```

Webkit uses a prefix for keyframes too. Complete example:

```
@keyframes anim{
  to{transform:rotate(30deg);}
}
@-webkit-keyframes anim{
  to{-webkit-transform:rotate(30deg);}
}
#element{
  animation:anim;
  -webkit-animation:anim;
}
```

Note: I've used transform because I wanted to show that prefixes are used in the prefixed version of keyframes only